# In this For loop count is not increasing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, model-view-controller, e-commerce

```
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    int count = 1;
                    <tr>
                        <td>@count</td>
                        <td>@item.ProductName</td>
                        <td>

                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "ProductEdit", new { productId = item.ProductId })
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    count = count + 1;
                }

            </tbody>
```

This code is to display the products in a table with serial number as count but the count is not increasing

Comment: Think really hard of what is actually happening INSIDE the loop....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the variable *outside* of the for loop, or it will not increase:

```
<tbody>
@{
    int count = 1;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {                
        <tr>
            <td>@count</td>
            <td>@item.ProductName</td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "ProductEdit", new { productId = item.ProductId })
            </td>

        </tr>
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are reassigning it to 1 for every iteration , initialize it before the loop starts

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the count value before the foreach iterates over the data, otherwise the count value will not increasee